# Changing framework from 3.5 to 4.0 at Server

Tags: c#, web-config, .net-framework-version

I know my Question is little bit basic but have to ask about this:

i have my website build in Visual Studio 2008 with .Net framework 3.5
that site is hosted on my server.

now because of some specific reason i have to install framework 4.0 to the server.
and i just want to know that my site will be okk with it or not.

I mean if i change my framework from 3.5 to 4.0 then is there some changes i should make to my site or that site will run fine as before.

Comment: keep the iis framework version to 3.5 as it is..

Comment: no i cant i hav made a service in 4.0 and now for running that service on server i need to install 4.0
i jst want to make sure that by installing 4.0 i shouldn't have to make changes in my site

Comment: answer is you dont have to..Go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also change Framework Version in the application pool of your WebSite.
[image: pool]

Basically, remember that Framework version != CLR Version.

In your case, .NET Framework 3.5 = CLR 2.0 + (C# 3.0 | VB9)

Comment: your site should also be compiled with .net 4.

Comment: actually at server in main folder a folder named Hash want framework 4.0 only so is it possible that without changing app pool value for main can i change app pool of that folder only as i have made that folder as an applicatin

Comment: @AbhishekMathur Yes you can have a WebSite with a CLR Version, and sub applications with another CLR Version. Do not forget to compile your web site with .Net 4.

Comment: okk it means i can change it thank u...
will tell u if caught into another problem while changing...
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 3.5 and 4.0 have different CLR Versions and can be installed side by side on same machine.

That means your site will not see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem installing the framework 4 on the server. 
Your site should be fine as long as you don't change the target framework on the IIS appPool.
You can have all the frameworks installed on the same machine.

Comment: actually at server in main folder a folder named Hash want framework 4.0 only so is it possible that without changing app pool value for main can i change app pool of that folder only as i have made that folder as an applicatin